# How to use NSPR?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, nspr

I am writing a sample code and i would be using NSPR libraries! I work on MS VC++ and use visual studio 2010. How do I include these libraries and use it with windows?

My main goal is to achieve thread synchronization using [NSPR](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

`#pragma comment (lib, "nspr.lib");`

or add it in linker settings as an additional lib. the compiled lib file must also be in the same location as the solution file of your project.